# Unable to get 2560 X 1440 resolution to work

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, external-display, resolution

Problem -

I can't get 2560x1440  high resolution to work on my Dell 27" U2713HM Monitor.

Details -

I have a Dell E6520 LAPTOP running 64 bit Windows 8. The highest resolution on the laptop is 1920x1080.

It shows 2 display adapters under Device Manager

- Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000
- NVIDIA NVS 4200M

I checked to make sure drivers for both are latest.
In my task tray I have both Intel graphics and NVIDIA managers.

I bought a Dell 27" U2713HM Monitor to use 2560 X 1440 resolution.  Installed the Dell Display manager, latest drivers etc.

Connected monitor using Dual Link DVI through my docking station.

I just cant get the 2560 X 1440 high resolution.  It only gives me 1920 X 1080 on the monitor. I even tried the HDMI connection.

Is this because my laptop display card has max resolution of 1920 X 1080?

So in order to use a certain max resolution, the display card in my laptop needs to support it?

If I see 2 display adaptors in Device manager, does it mean I have 2 display cards?

How can I get the Dell 27" U2713HM Monitor 2560 X 1440 resolution to work?

Comment: I have now solved this with a registry hack.. http://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible/756813#756813

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both the Intel and Nvidia GPU seem to have a max resolution that is dependent on the connection type.

From [Intel Graphics Reference](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics/) and [nVidia](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvs_techspecs.html) the max resolution:

- Display Port: 2560x1600
- HDMI/DVI: 1920x1080
- Analog VGA: 2048x1536

The Intel link is less clear that HDMI and DVI are less than the DisplayPort but there are a number of other sources that claim this ([here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/10054/solved-whats-the-max-resoulion-supported-on-intel-hd-3000/), [here](http://communities.intel.com/thread/27144) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible)).

The [specs](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_latitude_laptop/latitude-e6520_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf) to your laptop show that it only has HDMI out which appears to be the limiting factor. You would need to have a display port out on your laptop and into your monitor to use the larger resolution.

To answer your other questions:

- Yes your max resolution will be limited by the max that the video adapters will support.
- Yes you have two adapters but the OS is supposed to dynamically handle which one is used (see [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html), [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120321091513AAVe8OA) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/358222/how-to-enable-nvidia-optimus-in-asus-notebookgt520m))

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-022544.htm) - "Can I get a list of resolutions that my Intel graphics support?". Just wondering how you found that Intel GPU only supports 1920X1080.  Also, If I see 2 display adaptors in Device manager, does it mean I have 2 display cards (intel and NVIDIA)?  How do I use display port in multi-mode ?  Do you think the laptop uses NVIDIA adaptor for external monitors?

Comment: @AmitPhatarphekar added links and updated my answer. I think you are limited by the HDMI out.

Comment: I'm using a docking station which has display port option.  Just picked up a display port cable and wallah...it worked with Display Port. I'm getting the max resolution now.  Appreciate the links and other information.  Helped out.

Answer (score 1):

Update to my last post: While the DisplayPort cable didn't work when connected to my Dell Laptop docking station's DisplayPort, and while it didn't work if I connected it to my laptop's DisplayPort while the laptop was in the docking station, once I removed the laptop from the docking station and connected the cable to the laptop's DisplayPort and rebooted, VOILA, I finally got full resolution on the Dell Ultrasharp. Hope this helps someone else...it suggests maybe there's something wrong with the docking station's DisplayPort.  No problem, I'll just not use it.  Once you get the Ultrasharp displaying in full resolution, you will be a Very Happy Camper, so don't give up until you've tried all possible combinations.  Good luck; hope this helps someone else!

Comment: If this is an update to your last post, please use the `edit` link beneath your last post to add the information; do not post the information as another answer.

Comment: I don't see where this guy's supposed first post is.